# Remove docs from mongodb collection and leave one by two conditions

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection about vehicles's signals. Per day and per vehicle, I have a lot of documents. What I want is only leave one document per day and per vehicle, principally the last one per day. Any options to solve this?

The structure of my collection is something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5e067c1b6c7d95203754a5db",
  "account": {
    "account_id": 7001
  },
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "carrier": "CARRIERABC",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
  "vehicle_type": 3,
  "provider": "PROVIDERXYZ",
  "MIN_CONNECTION": "2019-12-18T00:00:04.000Z",
  "MAX_CONNECTION": "2019-12-18T23:59:56.000Z",
  "AVG": 96.248069842024
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I have removed all other properties for simplicity)

Let's imagine your you want only one and latest record per date and num_plate.

```
db.entries.update({
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
}, {
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
  "VALUE" : 1
}, {
  upsert: true
});

db.entries.update({
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
}, {
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
  "VALUE":  2
}, {
  upsert: true
});

db.entries.update({
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
}, {
  "date": "2019-12-18",
  "num_plate": "JHGF78",
  "VALUE": 3
}, {
  upsert: true
});
```

If you run the above queries, you will only have have the last record for that vehicle, because your matching criteria is there.